# Register Form Android Studio

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication

Good day everyone

I created a registarion form for my android app. the mysql database is on localhost:3306 logcat gives me the following error when I try to register:

```
07-27 19:54:13.448    3923-3944/com.burgames.mysqltest E/Buffer Error﹕ Error          converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
07-27 19:54:13.448    3923-3944/com.burgames.mysqltest E/JSON Parser﹕ Error   parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
07-27 19:54:13.448    3923-3944/com.burgames.mysqltest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL     EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: com.burgames.mysqltest, PID: 3923
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.toString()' on a null object reference
        at com.burgames.mysqltest.register$CreateUser.doInBackground(register.java:110)
        at com.burgames.mysqltest.register$CreateUser.doInBackground(register.java:73)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

AsynkTas subclass looks like:

```
public class register extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText user, pass;
private Button  mRegister;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

//php login script

//localhost :
//testing on your device
//put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
//or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
// private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/register.php";

//testing on Emulator:
private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3306/webservice/register.php";

//testing from a real server:
//private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.yourdomain.com/webservice/register.php";

//ids
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

    mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    new CreateUser().execute();

}

class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(register.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            //Posting user data to script
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            // full json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                finish();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(register.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

The XML looks like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Username" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
        android:layout_below="@+id/username"
        android:text="Password" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Android Remote Server Tutorial"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:text="Register" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I found out that the error might is on the login script:

```
package com.burgames.mysqltest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class login extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //php login script location:

    //localhost :
    //testing on your device
    //put your local ip instead,  on windows, run CMD > ipconfig
    //or in mac's terminal type ifconfig and look for the ip under en0 or en1
    // private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/webservice/login.php";

    //testing on Emulator:
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3306/webservice/login.php";

    //testing from a real server:
    //private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.yourdomain.com/webservice/login.php";

    //JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //setup input fields
        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username_edit_text);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password_edit_text);

        //setup buttons
        mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);

        //register listeners
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.login:
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
                break;
            case R.id.register:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, register.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", (HashMap<String, String>) params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    Intent i = new Intent(login.this, readComments.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Im going trough this turorial
http://www.mybringback.com/android-sdk/13193/android-mysql-php-json-part-5-developing-the-android-application/

Ports and login credentials to db are okay. I launch it with the emulator... so IP should also be okay.

I have copied everything after I have received the error.
You you guys have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of`. your json is invalid... e.g. whatever you're fetching returned nothing, instead of json.

Comment: @MarcB I've returned the username and password... which worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NullPointerException is on this line: `Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());`

The first step is to check if it's null before you de-reference your json reference: `if (json != null)`.

I recently [wrote a blog post](http://danielnugent.blogspot.com/2015/06/updated-jsonparser-with.html) about the JSONParser class, and updated it to use [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead of the now deprecated methods the old JSONParser class uses.

I just re-worked your code a bit and got it working with the new JSONParser class.

First, here is the new JSONParser class, just replace your old one with this one:

```
import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class JSONParser {

    String charset = "UTF-8";
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream wr;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL urlObj;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    StringBuilder sbParams;
    String paramsString;

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      HashMap<String, String> params) {

        sbParams = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            try {
                if (i != 0){
                    sbParams.append("&");
                }
                sbParams.append(key).append("=")
                        .append(URLEncoder.encode(params.get(key), charset));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            i++;
        }

        if (method.equals("POST")) {
            // request method is POST
            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

                paramsString = sbParams.toString();

                wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                wr.writeBytes(paramsString);
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else if(method.equals("GET")){
            // request method is GET

            if (sbParams.length() != 0) {
                url += "?" + sbParams.toString();
            }

            try {
                urlObj = new URL(url);

                conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();

                conn.setDoOutput(false);

                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);

                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        try {
            //Receive the response from the server
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line);
            }

            Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        conn.disconnect();

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(result.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON Object
        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Here is the modified Register Activity code that uses the new JSONParser class.

Note that I made a few changes.  The username and password are passed into the AsyncTask through the varargs, this is a cleaner approach that what you had previously, and you should not be referencing UI elements in a background Thread.

I also switched the BasicNameValuePair params to use a HashMap, since BasicNameValuePair is deprecated in API level 22.

Here is the full class code:

```
public class Register extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mRegister;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:3306/webservice/register.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //send username and password here:
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();
        new CreateUser().execute(username, password);

    }

    class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Check for success tag
            int success = 0; //initialize to zero

            //not needed:
            //String username = user.getText().toString();
            //String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
                //Remove this code:
                /*
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
                */

                //Use a HashMap instead with the varargs:
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", args[0]);
                params.put("password", args[1]);

                Log.d("request!", "starting");

                //Posting user data to script
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // full json response
                //added null check:
                if (json != null) {
                    Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
                    // json success element
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                      Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                      finish();
                      return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                    } else {
                      Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                      return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                    }
                 }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Result after testing the code above:

```
 D/JSON Parser﹕ result: {"success":1,"message":"Login successful."}
 D/Login attempt﹕ {"message":"Login successful.","success":1}
 D/User Created!﹕ {"message":"Login successful.","success":1}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have received a new error

        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.json.JSONObject.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at com.burgames.mysqltest.register$CreateUser.doInBackground(register.java:114)

Comment: @ManuelBürge I just noticed one thing, and updated the code in `doInBackground()`, there was still code de-referencing `json` even if it was null.  Take a look at the updated answer!

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. It nearly worked. there is just a parsing error, i might be able to fix :)...
If you want to know it:
07-31 17:32:49.391    2076-2095/com.burgames.mysqltest E/JSON Parser﹕ Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: @manuel Great!  As for your last issue, you're not getting a valid JSON response.  It could be an error message coming back in xml format.  what is the log entry for result.toString() showing?

Comment: might be this one?
.
07-31 18:29:01.453    2119-2141/com.burgames.mysqltest W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-31 18:29:01.453    2119-2141/com.burgames.mysqltest W/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa511bf20, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Comment: @ManuelBürge That's not it.  It would be the one in JSONParser from this line of code: `Log.d("JSON Parser", "result: " + result.toString());`

Comment: i ran the debugger. i saw that this line of code cant be reached. it goes directly to  catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Answer (score 0):

i think the error maybe is this line 
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));

change for 
 params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username=", username));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("&password=", password));

Comment: This would not be the cause of a NullPointerException.  Also, what makes you think this would be a good change, or would work at all?

Comment: im develop another services post whit username and password and always send variables "&username=", but y dont think your problem that it, see my another answer

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is just wrong.  There is no need to use `=` or `&` with BasicNameValuePair objects.